# I'm trying to compare time using dayjs as well as jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dayjs

I am trying to get the time in the second div from this code, then add a class to the first line. The code I have used here is that

```
function getSchduleTime(projectTime) {
  var projectTime = $("div.col-2 col-md-1 hour text-center py-3").text()
  if (dayjs().format("h:mm A")==projectTime) {
    $( "#hour" ).addClass( "row time-block present" );
  } else if (dayjs().isAfter(projectTime, 'minute')) {
    $( "#hour" ).addClass( "row time-block future" );
  } else {
    $( "#hour" ).addClass( "row time-block past" );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Class selector:

```
function getScheduleTime(projectTime) {
  var $row = $('.row').first();
  var $time = $row.find('.hour');
  var timeString = $time.text();
  var time = dayjs(timeString, 'h:mm A');

  if (dayjs().isSame(time, 'minute')) {
    $row.addClass('present');
  } else if (dayjs().isBefore(time, 'minute')) {
    $row.addClass('future');
  } else {
    $row.addClass('past');
  }
}
```